# Docusign Invalid managed token ID and/or secret in Php

Tags: docusignapi

I have to create an embedded URL using DocuSign PHP API(docusign/esign-client). It generated successfully but after 7-8hrs this embedded URL id displayed an error message Invalid managed token ID and/or secret.[image]

Please help me any thing need to do.

Answer (score 1):

When you mention embedded URL, are you referring to embedded signing URL or embedded sending URL? Either case, the URL is valid only for 5 minutes from the point of creation and is only valid for use one-time after which it is invalidated. You would need to create a new URL after that time has elapsed.

Comment: I have created an embedded URL for signing to the client when if this expires we have a refresh token generate a new embedded URL but after 5-7hrs this link got a managed_token error
e.g. https://account-d.docusign.com/managed_token/v1/redeem/?slt=eyJ0... 

any settings backend or any solution for this issue

Comment: Make sure you are storing the entire URL. I've only managed to get this error if the URL is missing a few characters in the managed_token